# Having two different topics within same windows server service bus namespace in WCF endpoint

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-binding, azureservicebus

I have two endpoints defined pointing to two different service bus topics. With same transportClientEndpointBehavior and on same service.

```
<endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="securityBehavior">

          <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
            <tokenProvider>
              <windowsAuthentication>
                <stsUris>
                  <stsUri value="https://on-permises:9355/Namespace" />
                </stsUris>
              </windowsAuthentication>
            </tokenProvider>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
</endpointBehaviors>

<customBinding>
        <binding name="messagingBinding" >
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="None" writeEncoding="utf-8"  >
            <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <netMessagingTransport/>
        </binding>
</customBinding>

<endpoint name="endpoint1"
           address="sb://on-permises/Namespace/topic1"
                   listenUri="sb://on-permises/Namespace/topic1/subscriptions/sub"
                   binding="customBinding"
                   bindingConfiguration="messagingBinding"
                   contract="WCFService.IService1"
                   behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior" />

        <endpoint name="endpoint2"
           address="sb://on-permises/Namespace/topic2"
                   listenUri="sb://on-permises/Namespace/topic2/subscriptions/sub"
                   binding="customBinding"
                   bindingConfiguration="messagingBinding"
                   contract="WCFService.IService2"
                   behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior" />
```

Once i run the application, I get the error :
System.ArgumentException: The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.TransportClientEndpointBehavior'. This collection only supports one instance of each type.
Parameter name: item

I tried by defining two different endpoint behaviors, but get the same error.
any help here will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the work around solution, the issue was service host was trying to add these two service endpoints in WSDL/Metadata. which was not necessary. So with the help of  ServiceMetadataContractBehavior (IContractBehavior ) stopped exposing the WSDL/Metadata .

Any better approach or correction please let me know.

```
public class DisableContractMetadata : Attribute, IContractBehavior

    {

        public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)

        {

        }


        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)

        {



        }


        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)

        {

            /// Here ServiceMetadataContractBehavior type is derived from IContractBehavior

            /// MetadataGenerationDisabled property of ServiceMetadataContractBehavior type = flase disables disables exposing WSDL 

            contractDescription.ContractBehaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataContractBehavior() { MetadataGenerationDisabled = true });

        }


        public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)

        {



        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the above answer is incomplete as it doesn't actually implement `IContractBehavior`.

As this is caused by hosting multiple services, you can also do it in the host:

```
ContractDescription contractDescription = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(MyService));
contractDescription.ContractBehaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataContractBehavior() { MetadataGenerationDisabled = true });
```

Or, if you have multiple contracts on a type, use this:

```
private static void DisableMetadataGeneration(Type serviceType)
{
    // prevent this error due to hosting multiple services:
    // System.ArgumentException: The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.TransportClientEndpointBehavior'. This collection only supports one instance of each type.
    foreach (Type contractType in GetContracts(serviceType))
    {
        ContractDescription contractDescription = ContractDescription.GetContract(contractType, serviceType);
        contractDescription.ContractBehaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataContractBehavior() { MetadataGenerationDisabled = true });
    }
}

private static Type[] GetContracts(Type serviceType)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(serviceType.IsClass);

    Type[] interfaces = serviceType.GetInterfaces();

    List<Type> contracts = new List<Type>();

    foreach (Type type in interfaces)
    {
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), false).Any())
        {
            contracts.Add(type);
        }
    }

    return contracts.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: FYI, `ContractDescription.GetContract` appears to return a temporary value -- if you change it, the changes don't get saved.  You need to modify the `endpoint.Contract` instead.